# Best Approach for Readable Ordered AsyncTask Code

Tags: java, android

I'm going round in circles trying different techniques but every time hitting a different snag.

Ideally I want my code to look something like;

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  SomeMethod();
  new SomeAsyncTask().execute();
  SomeOtherMethod();
  new SomeOtherAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

But I need each method to be executed in order (and to wait for the previous to complete). Let's imagine the first AsyncTask authenticates and stores an authentication token in a static somewhere- this is then needed for the calls which follow.

My AsyncTasks have to be Async as they are communicating with an API.

I know I could use the `onPostExecute()` methods of the AsyncTasks but I don't like the mess this creates (having to jump around the code).

I know I could also create an interface and pass a class in to my AsyncTask but this doesn't help a great deal either (code still jumps around).

I thought I had come up with the perfect solution, calling `SomeAsyncTask.execute().get()` to wait until the task completes before continuing with the next line of code BUT I've hit a few issues with that today too.

Are there any other techniques I might be able to use to achieve clean code with a mix of foreground and background thread activity?

**EDIT** At the moment I am considering whether I can make all of my method non-async but then call them from an async- more like;

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground( final Void ... params ) {
              SomeMethod();
              SomeMethod2();
              SomeOtherMethod();
              SomeOtherMethod2();
              return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( final Void result ) {
            // any ui stuff
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

**EDIT2** Current favoured solution is;

Define a "PostExecute" interface in my AsyncTask;

```
public class GetMerchantDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Context mContext;
    private PostExecute mDelegate;
    public interface PostExecute {
        void Callback();
    }

    public GetMerchantDataAsync(Context context, PostExecute delegate) {
        mContext = context;
        mDelegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
        mDelegate.Callback();
    }
}
```

Then define an instance of the interface and pass it on the constructor;

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    private final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new GetMerchantDataAsync(context, getMerchantDataPostExecute).execute();
    }

    private GetMerchantDataAsync.PostExecute getMerchantDataPostExecute = new GetMerchantDataAsync.PostExecute() {
        @Override
        public void Callback() {
            DoSomethingElse();
        }
    };
}
```

It's a little bit messy (not a single block of code) but it almost reads as a single block and hopefully with sensible/consistent naming will be easily readable.

Comment: Why not create a subclass of AsyncTask that has an execute method with a callback param, that is called from ```onPostExecute``` and calls the super.execute (you should use executeOnExecutor tho). In this way you could have everything in one place.

Comment: That sounds interesting, can you provide an example?

Comment: `AsyncTask` has `publishProgress` which is used to implicitly call `onProgressUpdate`. You can use it to send information to your UIThread from within `doInBackground`, It is often used for updating the progress counter.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to skin this cat and a few nice async await libraries you can use, similar to Promise.

Or you can also simply do **onPostExecute** call backs inline if that fits your needs and call the next step onPostExecute, assuming life cycle is still valid.

However, if you want some nice clean code, you should consider Kotlin and Coroutines.

Example with Timeout, cancellation and error handling:

Notice the withTimeout and the withContext calls. Those allow you to await on the contents within before moving on. Also as an added bonus, the method here is a suspendable coroutine which means the caller can wait on it as well. You resume the caller with c.resume(returnValueType).

If you find this too complicated, then I would stick with your onPostExecute, but what most developers forget on AsyncTasks are.

- AsyncTasks should be canceled if you exit the Activity typically
- AsyncTasks can complete out of order if you are allowing threadpool
  management
- Object locks must be wrapped to ensure concurrent
  modification of variables does not become a problem.
- Callbacks should handle errors and not just the positive route
- Timeouts have to be managed outside of the Async task adding much more bloat.

So you see, simply doing a myAsyncTask.execute{onPostExecute(value){//dostuff}}
may look like simple fast code, it is definitely prone to errors if you don't handle all the niche cases that can occur.

The Coroutines have provided nice wrappers around all of this in easy to read brackets.

```
private suspend fun updateConfigurationWithChanges() : Boolean = suspendCoroutine { c ->
        A35Log.v(mClassTag, "updateConfigurationWithChanges")
        setIsActionInProgress(true)
        mSaveOrUpdateJob = launch(UI) {
            try{
                withTimeout(TIMEOUT_FOR_DB_INTERACTION_MS){
                    showProgressDialog(mClassTag, "Saving", false)
                    mSelectedConfiguration!!.setLastSavedDateStr(DateTimeHelper.getNowTimeStamp())
                    val updatedRecordCount = withContext(DefaultDispatcher){ SSDBHelper.updateConfiguration(mSelectedConfiguration!!) }
                    if(updatedRecordCount > 0){
                        showFancyToast("Successfully updated", true, FancyToast.SUCCESS)
                        c.resume(true)
                    }else{
                        showFancyToast("Error while updating, please try again or press back", true, FancyToast.SUCCESS)
                        c.resume(false)
                    }
                }
            }catch(ex: JobCancellationException){
                showFancyToast("Save canceled", true, FancyToast.ERROR, "Save canceled: ${ex.message}")
                c.resume(false)
            }catch (ex: TimeoutCancellationException) {
                showFancyToast("Timed out updating, please try again or press back", true, FancyToast.ERROR, "Timed out updating database: ${ex.message}")
                c.resume(false)
            }catch(ex: Exception){
                showFancyToast("Error updating database, please try again or press back", true, FancyToast.ERROR, "Error updating database: ${ex.message}")
                c.resume(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course it is still good practice to cancel if the user leaves your screen if it doesn't hurt anything.

```
 override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    if(mSaveOrUpdateJob != null && mSaveOrUpdateJob!!.isActive) {
        A35Log.v(mClassTag, "canceling saveOrUpdate job")
        mSaveOrUpdateJob?.cancel()
    }
}
```

But at the end of the day, do what's best for your situation, if managing the asyncTask and onPostExecute works for your needs and you have all your i's dotted and your t's crossed you should be fine going that route as well.

Also just for completeness if you are wondering how to call and await this above method it would look like this.

```
 fun myButtonClick(){
         launch(UI) {
                if(mIsNewConfiguration){
                    //save first if new
                    if(withContext(DefaultDispatcher){ isNewOrUnchangedName() }) {
                        if (withContext(DefaultDispatcher) { saveNewConfigurationToDatabase() }) {
                            refreshCurrentNamesList()
                            launchConnectAndSendToDeviceFlow()
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    //update first if changes made
                    if(withContext(DefaultDispatcher){ isNewOrUnchangedName() }) {
                        if(DeviceAndConfigurationHelper.hasConfigurationModelChanged(mOriginalCopyConfiguration!!, mSelectedConfiguration!!)){
                            if(withContext(DefaultDispatcher) { updateConfigurationWithChanges() }){
                                refreshCurrentNamesList()
                                launchConnectAndSendToDeviceFlow()
                            }
                        }else{
                            launchConnectAndSendToDeviceFlow()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Kotlin and coroutines look way too complex. I really liked the idea of `do onPostExecute call backs inline if that fits your needs and call the next step` but I was seeing a warning about needing to be static, leaks and also envisioned an issue if I need to pass any data back from the background?

Comment: Yeah it's a bit of a learning curve, I'll give you that, but once you got it, it's easy to keep repeating and gives a ton of benefits to handling your threading and code management for good memory and threading practices, but you are fine to do the onpostexecute inline, just make sure you are checking the validity of your activity's life when you return and if you need to pass the context (aka activity) make sure you store it as a WeakReference<Activity> instead of actual reference to avoid static memory leak warnings.

Comment: And if I need to pass data back from my AsyncTask to the method called `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Yup, you specify that when you define your AsyncTask class that extends it with generics AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> so when you override the task make sure you specify the Result type, so that your onPostExecute will have the result type you need.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches, depending on your constraints you can pick any of them, one using custom async tasks:

Create a custom `AsyncTask` which will be inherited by all your async tasks (or it can be done inline too):

```
public abstract class BaseAsyncTask<T, U, V> extends AsyncTask<T, U, V> {

    public interface Callback<X> {

        void onComplete(X param);
    }

    private Callback mainCallback;

    public void execute(Callback<V> callback, T... params) {
        mainCallback = callback;
        executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(V v) {
        super.onPostExecute(v);
        if (mainCallback != null) {
            mainCallback.onComplete(v);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used like this for your case:

```
public static class TestThinghy {

    BaseAsyncTask<String, String, String> task = new BaseAsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    void firstFunOnMainThread() {
        //....do whatever...///
    }

    void runEverything() {
        firstFunOnMainThread();
        new BaseAsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                return "testing thinghy";
            }
        }.execute(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String param) {
                secondRunOnMainThread();
                //you can start new async here, or better start it from a different methond
            }
        }, "the other string param");
    }

    void secondRunOnMainThread() {
        ///...whatever here
    }
}
```

The other approach is using RxJava, it's a powerful approach that gives you a ton of ways to chain tasks like this and decide how to run them, for this approach I would let you to do some research.